# React Router does not redirect on exact path

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Can somebody explain why the exact redirection is not working?

```
    <Provider store={store}>
        <BrowserRouter history={history}>
            <Switch>
                <Route path="/user*" component={UserApplication} />
                <Route exact from="/" to="/user/login" component={UserApplication} />
                <Route component={ ErrorFileNotFound } />
            </Switch>
        </BrowserRouter>
    </Provider>
ReactDOM.render(route, document.getElementById('root'));
```

If I change the second route to  it doesn't show any error, but doesn't load UserApplication either.

UserApplication:

```
class UserApplication extends React.Component {
    render() {
        console.log(this.props.location)
        return (
            <Provider store={store}>
                <BrowserRouter history={history}>
                    <Switch>
                        <Route exact from="/user" to="/user/login" component={Login} />
                        <Route path="/user/login" component={Login} />
                        <Route path="/user/register" component={Registration} />
                        <Route component={ ErrorFileNotFound } />
                    </Switch>
                </BrowserRouter>
            </Provider>
        );
    }
}
```

- /user is working and loading the UserApplication component according to UserApplication routes
- /user/login is working and loading the UserApplication component
- / not working and loading ErrorFileNotFound component

The idea is to redirect from / to /user/login

Comment: Where are the `Redirect` components? `Route` doesn't handle redirects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should be using Redirect instead of route. [Here](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Redirect) you can read more about that.